# Здравствуйте не могу вывести данные mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю фильтр, и не могу обработать данные - не могу вывести результат. Сам запрос через echo получается, а вот всё вместе - нет.

Ошибки:

```
Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/bh60658/catalog.richlifeyar.ru/filter/index.php on line 372

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/bh60658/catalog.richlifeyar.ru/filter/index.php on line 372

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/bh60658/catalog.richlifeyar.ru/filter/index.php on line 374
```

Код:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `catalog`";
    if ($where) $sql .= "WHERE $where";
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "bh60658_catalog", "idW]]WNLCe;{", "bh60658_catalog");
    if (!$link) {
    die('Ошибка соединения: ' . mysql_error());
     }
    echo 'Успешно соединились';

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $file = explode(',', $myrow['filename']);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($file as $val) {
          if (++$i > 1) break;
          echo "<div class='col-md-3'>
                              <div class='card'>
                                <img class='card-img-top' src='../".$myrow['catalog']."".$val."' alt='Card image cap' style='width: 210px'>
                                <div class='card-block'>
                                  <h4 class='card-title'>".$myrow['prace']."</h4>
                                  <p class='card-text'> ".$myrow['area']."</p>
                                  <a href='http://catalog.richlifeyar.ru/roomInfo/index.php?val=".$myrow['id']."'' val='".$myrow['id']."' class='btn btn-primary'>Подробнее</a>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                         </div>"; 
    }
  }
```

а вот весь код целиком

```
<?php
  function addWhere($where, $add, $and = true) {
    if ($where) {
      if ($and) $where .= " AND $add";
      else $where .= " OR $add";
    }
    else $where = $add;
    return $where;
  }
  if (!empty($_POST["submit"])) {
    $where = "";
    if ($_POST["property_type"]) $where = addWhere($where, "`property_type` = '".htmlspecialchars($_POST["property_type"]))."'";
    if ($_POST["room"]) $where = addWhere($where, "`room` IN (".htmlspecialchars(implode(",", $_POST["room"])).")");
    if ($_POST["area"]) $where = addWhere($where, "`area` = '".htmlspecialchars($_POST["area"]))."'";
    if ($_POST["space_one"]) $where = addWhere($where, "`prace` >= '".htmlspecialchars($_POST["space_one"]))."'";
    if ($_POST["space_two"]) $where = addWhere($where, "`prace` <= '".htmlspecialchars($_POST["space_two"]))."'";
    if ($_POST["prace_one"]) $where = addWhere($where, "`prace` >= '".htmlspecialchars($_POST["prace_one"]))."'";
    if ($_POST["prace_two"]) $where = addWhere($where, "`prace` <= '".htmlspecialchars($_POST["prace_two"]))."'";


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `catalog`";
    if ($where) $sql .= "WHERE $where";
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "bh60658_catalog", "idW]]WNLCe;{", "bh60658_catalog");
    if (!$link) {
    die('Ошибка соединения: ' . mysql_error());
     }
    echo 'Успешно соединились';

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $file = explode(',', $myrow['filename']);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($file as $val) {
          if (++$i > 1) break;
          echo "<div class='col-md-3'>
                              <div class='card'>
                                <img class='card-img-top' src='../".$myrow['catalog']."".$val."' alt='Card image cap' style='width: 210px'>
                                <div class='card-block'>
                                  <h4 class='card-title'>".$myrow['prace']."</h4>
                                  <p class='card-text'> ".$myrow['area']."</p>
                                  <a href='http://catalog.richlifeyar.ru/roomInfo/index.php?val=".$myrow['id']."'' val='".$myrow['id']."' class='btn btn-primary'>Подробнее</a>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                         </div>"; 
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Если бы это был весь код целиком, то тут было бы минимум 374 строк. Значит это не весь код целиком или не тот файл, где ошибка

Comment: но он всего один, и если в нем написать echo $sql то получится запрос который я выбрал а вот ораотать я его не могу из бд, имею виду вставить данные на страницу

Comment: Вы используете `mysqli` для коннекта, а для запроса и вытягивания данных `mysql`. Определитесь, что именно вы хотите использовать. Кстати при этом еще и не передавая идентификатор соединения

Answer (score 1):

> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/bh60658/catalog.richlifeyar.ru/filter/index.php on line 372

У Вас ошибка подключения. Поскольку в сообщении в полном имени учётной записи имеется имя хоста, но отсутствует имя пользователя - то Вы его не передаёте (либо передаёте настолько неправильно, что сервер не может понять, что это имя пользователя).

Пока эта проблема не будет устранена, на остальные можете не обращать внимания.

А ещё очень странно, что в одном коде Вы рядом используете и mysqli_connect, и mysql_query. Имеет смысл определиться с библиотекой и оставить только одну.

Comment: Вангую, что причина именно в миксовании mysqli с mysql и пропущенном идентификаторе соединения

Comment: так $result = mysql_query($sql, $link); ?? сделал такие ошибки появились

Comment: Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in /home/bh60658/catalog.richlifeyar.ru/filter/index.php on line 372

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/bh60658/catalog.richlifeyar.ru/filter/index.php on line 374

Comment: @Koly хотя бы читайте что вам пишут..... у вас соединение через mysql**i**  а запросы через другой драйвер

Comment: извините что туплю просто понять не могу , я же сделал тут  $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

Comment: Вы использовали для подключения одну библиотеку, а получать данные хотите через другую. Не получится. Чтобы войти в дверь. надо открыть дверь. а не окно...

Comment: вроде чуть понял $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "bh60658_catalog", "idW]]WNLCe;{", "bh60658_catalog"); а не $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "bh60658_catalog", "idW]]WNLCe;{", "bh60658_catalog");

Comment: извините за моё недопонимание, но еще одна ошибка осталась Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/bh60658/catalog.richlifeyar.ru/filter/index.php on line 374

Comment: В методе MySQL_Connect нет параметра "база данных" (четвёртый параметр). Там должен быть параметр "новое соединение", булева типа. боюсь, что "bh60658_catalog" не сойдёт ни за True, ни за False...

Comment: сделал так  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "bh60658_catalog", "idW]]WNLCe;{"); та же ошибка

Comment: Займитесь отладкой. После КАЖДОГО оператора проверяйте, что он был выполнен без ошибки, и что результат строго тот, который Вы ожидаете. Только убедившись, что всё в порядке, приступайте к отладке следующего оператора.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50772/discussion-between-koly-and-akina).